# Add thousands separator to double in c#

Tags: c#, parsing, format, double

I am trying to format a double to a string format which contains thousands separators and all trailing decimal numbers in german number format. But I can't get it to work (am I really that foolish?).

What I want is the following:

```
Input: double doubleVal = 123456.789;
Output: 123.456,789
```

I already used NumberFormats and other stuff but I don't get what I want. Can somebody please help?

Comment: If you're building something that some users will use you should consider using the default system setting for decimals formatting

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd expect you should be able to do it with:

```
string text = value.ToString("N");
```

... specifying the German culture if it's not the thread's current culture.

Sample:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        double d = 123456.789;
        CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");

        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("N3", culture)); // 123.456,789
    }                   
}
```

Note that the 3 specifies the number of digits after the decimal point.

Comment: Ok, but the number of digits after the decimal point is changing and I don't want to round or trim.

Comment: @flashflail: If you're using `double`, you're getting rounding or trimming *anyway*. Your value isn't *exactly* 123.456789 to start with. If you want exact decimal values, you should be using `decimal`.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
string s = String.Format("{0:0,0.000}", 123456.789);
```

Comment: It's not commas for thousands that is required but a decimal point as thousands separator and then the comma to separate the integer value from the decimal places - German number format

Answer (score 2):

Just use custom format strings:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double d = 123456.789;
            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("de-DE");                        
            Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("N",ci));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```